# referencing a main method in an imported module from a newbie to Python

Tags: python, program-entry-point

Apologies if the thinking behind the question is wrong: just picking up Python as I go.
So I've written a python module that goes off to a database and gets a bunch of standard data that is used by lots of other modules, so I thought it would be good practise to build it as a reusable module.
So there is a class:

```
class TalkToOracle:
```

with an attribute

```
gres = None
```

a bunch of other functions, and a main function at the end

```
def main():
```

with a line I don't fully understand but seems to automatically run the main method when the class is referenced(?)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Main runs the functions in the class in order, and sticks the results in the attribute: gres

All runs great stands alone. The file is saves as GetOraData.py
I now want to reuse this code so.......
In another Python module

```
import GetOraData


class GetInstances:
    def oraInstanceData(self):
        log.info('Getting instance routing data')
        HAData = GetOraData.TalkToOracle()
        log.info('debug1')
```

All goes pear shaped from here.
I just want to run the other module, and access the results in the attribute gres.
I tried this (and every other variation I could think of) but no joy.
I feel I'm missing something fundamental.

```
HADATA.main()
log.info('debug2')
HADataSet = HAData.gres
log.info('debug3')
log.info('Query fetched ' + str(len(HADataSet)) + ' rows')
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

After some work, here is the modified code that still throws an error

```
import logging
import time
import uuid
import GetOraData
from datetime import datetime

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel('INFO')

class GetInstances:
    def oraInstanceData(self):
        log.info('Getting HA instance routing data')
        HAData = GetOraData.main()
        HADataSet = GetOraData.gres
        log.info('Query fetched ' + str(len(HADataSet)) + ' HA Instances to query')

def main():

    logging.basicConfig()
    start = time.time()

    #oracle routines

    oraInstances = GetInstances()
    oraInstances.oraInstanceData()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

error:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gres'

Comment: what is the problem you are having exactly? is this HADATA.main() a typo? is the code you are showing the one you are actually using?

Comment: Yes: although it's now changed after the answers given below to:        HAData = GetOraData.main()
HADataSet = GetOraData.gres which throes up an error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gres'

Comment: you just didn't put self when defining the class, did you?

Comment: How is ```gres``` defined? In your example, does ```GetInstances``` really need to be a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicity call the `main` module attribute of GetOraData:

```
GetOraData.main()
GetOraData.gres
```

When you import a module, all of its attributes are in *its* namespace.

- https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects
- http://pyvideo.org/video/1749/namespaces-in-python,
- http://pyvideo.org/search?models=videos.video&q=namespaces

Comment: This may be a really stupid question, but I thought the whole idea of OO programming is you declare a class, and then take an instance of that class. So the file is called GetOraData, but the class inside it is called TalktoOracle. Wouldn't I reference the class, not the file name?

Comment: to reference the class you have to import it this way:      from GetOraData import TalkToOracle

Comment: HAData = GetOraData.main()
        HADataSet = GetOraData.gres
gives the errAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gres'
which is defined in the main class in the GetOraData module class TalkToOracle:
    cur = None
    con = None
    gres = None

Comment: gres is not a module variable it is on the TalkToOracle class? to access it form the module it needs to be module level ... modules are objects (like classes) but just contain the globals for that file.

Answer (score 0):

`__name__` is the name of the current module. When the program is run as an application (not as an imported module), that name is `"__main__"`. This is what causes the code under it to run. The code under that test is not meant to be used as a module. It is very likely this code uses sys.argv (command line arguments), which aren't set up properly.

Check to see if there are functions in the other module which are meant be used as a module, with data structures you can call, likely some function or object.

Comment: HAData = GetOraData.main()
        HADataSet = GetOraData.gres
gives the errAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gres'
which is defined in the main class in the GetOraData module class TalkToOracle:
    cur = None
    con = None
    gres = None

Answer (score 0):

if your code looked something like this:

```
# GetOraData.py

class TalkToOracle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.gres = None

    def main(self):
        self.gres = 'Foo'
```

then you could have done something like this:

```
# GetInstances.py
from GetOraData import TalkToOracle

class GetInstances:

    def oraInstanceData(self):

       HAData = TalkToOracle()
       print HAData.gres
       # None

       HAData.main()
       print HAData.gres
       # Foo

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # test it
    x = GetInstances()
    x.oraInstanceData()

# $ python GetInstances.py
# None
# Foo
```

so you could have accessed 'gres' attribute and check the value.

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

is there to be executed when you call your program from the command line (i.e. python GetInstances.py). If you put this kind of thing in the other file (GetOraData.py) it would not be executed cause in this case this file is just being imported as a module by GetInstances.py